# Converting noise to sbytes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, noise

I want to generate noise as values between -128 and 127 (the range of sbytes) but perlin/simplex noise is generating floats between -1 and 1 and I can't figure out how can I convert it. For example like 0.5f means 64 or something like that. Do you have any idea on converting these values?

Comment: Well, what happens if you just multiple the value by 127 and cast to `sbyte`? That would get you a range of -127 to 127...

Comment: Try (byte)(noiseFloat * 127)

Comment: Well yeah its quite simple now as I think again anyway thank you for the quick answers

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Arduino background, I find myself always using their [map](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) function in Unity. It is used to scale from one range to another. You pass in the input to the function, then the range of that input which is `-1` to `1`. Finally you pass in the output range you want which is `-128f` and `127f`. The function will return the scaled value.

```
float mappedVal = mapValue(yourSimplexnoise, -1f, 1f, -128f, 127f);
```

---

```
float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lerp:

```
(sbyte)Mathf.Lerp(-128, 127, (noise+1)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

some like this.

```
float r = (Random.Range(-1f, 1f) + 1) / 2;
sbyte b = (sbyte)Mathf.Lerp(-128f,127f, r);
```